# Serial downvotes on my questions

Tags: support

I notice that I get downvotes on my questions following some pattern:

- The downvotes are on questions only, so they don't leave a -1 in the SDV's (serial downvoter's) reputation
- The downvotes are sparsely distributed over time, only one a day and three a week
- The SDV proceeds "bottom-up" starting with the lowest rated questions to the higher rated ones
- The downvotes aren't related to the content of the questions at all

Can a moderator or a Community manager with enough privileges look into this?

P.S. Any votes (up or down) should consider the value of the question or answer that is voted on, they should not be directed at the Original Poster(OP) of the item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @lemontree for showing me how to view votes given by users and for identifying potential sockpuppet accounts.

I have deleted the offending accounts. Most of this user's activity consisted of creating junk questions and answers, upvoting them and deleting them before anyone could notice. The user karma-farmed for his current primary account in this way.

By all indications, we are not dealing with a new person here, but with the person running the familiar old "prostorech"/"Ilya Prostov" account.

Comment: Thanks to you and @lemontree for looking into this. Given the amount of hacking spirit and determination I suspected the very same user to be responsible for that.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible for moderators to see for each user a list of the users having given and a list of the users having received the most votes (up and down) for that user. These lists are partial, showing only the users with the highest numbers of votes given/received relative to that user.
There is a user who has given you an unusual number of downvotes (30 downvotes cast in total, 12 (40%) on you). The other top downvoters on you as well as your top upvoters have much lower percentages (<= 25%). I can not see who received the remaining 18 downvotes and who received upvotes from that user, as the list of the most votes given by that user shows only you, which suggests that no other user has received unusually many up or downvotes from that user.

I am not entirely convinced that 40% is a high enough number to definitely be considered serial downvoting (though wouldn't object to a decision that yes), and I am also not aware of a possibility to manually un-do votes if not caught by the automatic radar. However, inspecting the votes received reveals that the user in question seems to have up to five sockpuppet accounts on this site (significant cross-upvoting and shared IP-addresses). I'll bring it up in moderator chat; quite possibly at least one of the accounts should be put down anyway, which would invalidate their votes.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this is a consequence of the SE model of evaluation. SE explicitly favors down-voting questions as contrasted with answers (and not that there is no up-vote reward). There is a non-generous interpretation of how multiple down-votes arise in cases where a question is not egregiously bad (blood in the water analogies), which is similar to serial close-voting. I think that is just the way it is on SE, and it's not obvious what there is that could be looked into. I question the assertion that down-voting is not related to content (how do you know it is?), and I suggest you consider the alternative explanation of ideological voting (it's not the structure of the argument, it's the viewpoint that you reflect). Ideological voting is not exactly rare on SE.

It's not that I dispute the premise that there exists personal animus (or adoration) as a basis for voting, it's that I don't see that this is a solvable problem under the SE model of content evaluation.

Comment: To this question: *(how do you know it is?)* the questions are quite diverse in topic and linguistic subdiscipline, they don't have common tags. The questions are neither new nor active, the SDV needs to find them from my profile or using some searches.

Comment: So you're saying that these are questions that have sunk into oblivion and haven't been answered, modified or commnuity-bumped for some months.

Comment: Yes, I do say so.