# Serial downvotes on my questions: Reply

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Linguistics Stack Exchange post: [Is Sanscrit a realy mother language?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/34803/is-sanscrit-a-realy-mother-language)

Would "jk - Reinstate Monica" like to tell us how he almost daily downvoted old posts of this user [Serial downvotes on my questions](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1885/serial-downvotes-on-my-questions) ?

You can't keep that fact in a secret (I have screenshorts, that were made by that user).

Comment: @lemontree He first started

Comment: @prash He first started

Comment: @jk - Reinstate Monica Would you like to tell us the full story ? Did you consistently 
 downvote posts of [this](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1885/serial-downvotes-on-my-questions) user ?

Answer (score 6):

Seriously? Two more new accounts already?

- https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/27639
- https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/27640

I literally destroyed 14 sockpuppet accounts yesterday. [How should sockpuppets be handled on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange) explains the StackExchange policy on sockpuppets.

These are my recommendations:

1. Stick to one account. I'll consider https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/24216/prostorech to be your main accont.
2. Honor the time suspension on that account.
3. Use that time to learn how the StackExchange system works. I don't mean the aspect of creating new accounts to farm for karma points. I mean learning how people ask good questions and how people provide good answers.

Your latest question, [Is Sanscrit a realy mother language?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/34803/is-sanscrit-a-realy-mother-language) shows absolutely no research effort. A very similar question has been asked before by someone else. If you had used the search feature, you would have seen that question and all the good answers it got in response. You would have gotten your answer without posting *anything* here.

Comment: "jk - Reinstate Monica" downvoted old posts of [that](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1885/serial-downvotes-on-my-questions) user for weeks -6/-4 per day

Comment: I would not wish you what you did with the labors of that guy

Comment: @samuelvirtanen Those accounts are all gone. I can't verify anything now. But most of the questions you have been asking were really bad in one way or another. I suggest you take my recommendations seriously. And please do not create more accounts.

Comment: You did not understand the situation completely. The accused should have the last word.You are a bad judge.

Comment: @samuelvirtanen I did not destroy the 14 accounts because of jk's complaint. I did that because creating sockpuppet accounts breaks StackExchange rules. I must have destroyed about 30 (or more) sockpuppet accounts in the last few months. And none of that had anything to do with jk's complaint. So please do not create more accounts.

Comment: That guy could not create a new post because he had -6/-4 per day from "jk - Reinstate Monica"

Comment: @samuelvirtanen 1. You can't know who was downvoting, but if the questions were any good, other people would have up-voted them. 2. My recommendations to you remain the same regardless of anything jk has said or done.

Comment: That guy know exactly because when "jk - Reinstate Monica" had a "feedback" the downvoting became more and more powerfull. You may ask @jk - Reinstate Monica about it.

Comment: Two users marked "Centum-satem environment in Proto-Slavic" as favorite. As a result of the outrages of "jk - Reinstate Monica" that post had -4 or even less..

Comment: @samuelvirtanen There is no point talking about irrelevant things. Here is the key factor: running sockpuppet accounts is against StackExchange rules. I have pasted a link to those rules in my answer above. **Do not** create new accounts. As simple as that.

Comment: Would you like that somebody constantly downvote your old posts in such a manner that you can not to create a new posts and another somebody say you come on, guy, I don’t see the problem

Comment: I demand jk - Reinstate Monic's explanation and you as an administrator in my opinion should help me with it

Comment: Even if he just answer that he don't know what i'm talking about, such an answer will suit me, because that will be the publical lie

Answer (score 5):

Since you explicitly address me, I hesitantly answer this:

I am an active voter on linguistics.se having cast more than 6.600 votes until today. The majority of my votes (almost 5k) are upvotes but there is a significant portion of downvotes, too. I usually vote on new questions and answers when they come up and I tend to ignore the author of the question or answer. So expect that almost any active user on this site has received some votes of mine.

Before the "current events" unfolded I was also active in the review queues and cast close votes, leave open votes, reopen votes, and leave closed votes. I have reduced that activity and only cast close votes on new or active questions right now.

Note that this site is not only for getting a question answered, but also a project of creating a comprehensive set of questions and answers for further reference by future users. Not every question is suitable for this purpose, a famous example being the identification of snippets of unknown languages. It is not unusual that the asker of the question gets an answer in the comments, however those questions are closed and removed from the site. This is not an offense at the original poster, it is just a policy of the site.

I consider the suitability of questions and answers as described above as one of my criteria in voting.

Now back to you: By your behaviour it seems that you currently do not share the goals of this site and you are not contributing to them. Take a break and think whether you want to change your usage patterns of this site or to move on to another place.

Comment: You said nothing!!! I asked the explicit question "Did you consistently downvote old posts of that user ?   Why ? What for ?

Comment: There is no smoke without fire.